# messed up repos in RHEL6

Tags: rhel, yum

I have RHEL 6 and have installed a bunch of the common repos (epel, etc) and somehow screwed up the repos (I think with a repo clean command)

I was getting errors specifically with EPEL, so I removed it:

```
rpm -e epel-release608.noarch
```

-> "error: package epel-releaase6-8.noarch is not installed"

and tried to reinstall it:

```
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

-> "package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed"

How do I get out of this infinite loop?

Comment: 1. `rpm -qa | grep epel-release`. 2. `yum remove <package_name.rpm>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure you have no epel-release packages left by listing all packages and grepping epel?

```
rpm -qa | grep epel
```

If there is no package in that list, you can also force install the epel-release package by running:

```
rpm -ivh --force epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: It's still in the list, but when trying to remove it, it fails due to dependencies (other repos need it).

Comment: yum repolist gives me an error: "Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel.  Please verify it's path and try again."

Answer (score -1):

The following combination of things worked for me:

- delete the actual files in `/etc/yum.repos.d`
- `yum clean all`
- `rpm -qa | grep epel`   (still shows)
- `yum remove epel*`
- `yum clean all`

This finally cleaned it out.